# native2ascii only for files which contain a specific text

Tags: unicode, ant, utf-8

I have a big load of .properties files in multi-languages, some contain unicode escaped formatting (\u304B\u3089). I'm interested in decoding all all of the files to non-escaped utf-8 chars ( から). I was thinking about using the native2ascii task reverse option in ANT, and I used this code for the build.xml:

```
<project>
<target name= "test">
    <native2ascii reverse="true" encoding="utf-8" src="build/test" dest="build/test/1"/>
</target>
</project>
```

Problem is that the files are mixed, some have escaped-unicode and some show the proper chars. As a result of running this build with ANT, the ones that were proper are now distorted. How can I modify the code so it will only run on the files which have unicode-escaped? (I was thinking about a condition which modifies only files which contain "\u", but I was not able to achieve this)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `copy` task, setting the source encoding and destination encoding to UTF-8:

```
<copy file="input.properties" tofile="output.properties" overwrite="true"
encoding="UTF-8" outputencoding="UTF-8" />
```

Comment: how can I do this for an entire directory and not just specific files?